# Are these connectors for SSDs? If so, which ones are they?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata, connection

I was looking to purchase an SSD today, and decided to do some research into the connectors for my PC and it. The connector for [the SSD](http://amzn.to/2eWPJ9h) was Serial ATA-600. I was checking out the ones in my PC, and I'm not sure if any work for this SSD. They're all positioned by my current 1TB HDD. (The lighting in my office isn't right to take a pic of them close-up, so I'll describe them)

One looks like this: [ • • • • ], with each • being a hole.

Another looks like: [□□□□] and it is significantly smaller than the one above. On its top is four gold lines, not unlike the ones found on a microSD card.

In case it helps, here's a pic of the side of my PC.

[image]

To the bottom right are the connectors I'd explained.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your SSD has two connectors: wider one being power, narrower one being Serial ATA data. Usually you can find a few connectors coming out of the power supply box that matches the shape of the power connector on the SSD (good old days when connectors could be connected together would work together). The Serial ATA data connector has a few identical counterpart on the mother board, and if you don't have the cables to connect it to the board yet you have to buy one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

[image: powah]

They’re all power connectors. You need one of those too, of course. The SATA power connector will do just fine. [Wikipedia offers more information on ATX power connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX#Original_ATX).

You also need a SATA data cable. You can get it Amazon or your favorite computer store. Just make sure it’s not too short.

Comment: Where do I connect the SATA data cable?

Comment: @pagie_ The back of the SSD will have 2 L shaped connections. The longer one is the power (pictured in your pic) and the shorter one is for data. The motherboard usually comes with these cables, not the drives themselves. The SATA data connector will connect the SSD to the motherboard, Same as the 1TB drive you currently have in there.

Comment: None of these fit the power connector on my SSD.

Comment: *Very* unlikely. The SATA Power connector will absolutely fit. Please provide the exact make and model of your SSD.